# How come Rukmi was a student of Lord Parashurama?

Tags: parashurama, harivamsa

Chapter 61 of Vishnu Parva, Harivamsa speaks about Rukmi's death.

And [verse 55](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_61_mpr.html) says

> tasminhate mahAvIrye nR^ipatau bhIShmakAtmaje |
> drumabhArgavatulye vai drumabhArgavashikShite ||

> As the great valiant king, the son of bhIShmaka, equal to druma and bhArgava(rAma) and trained by druma and bhArgava(rAma), was killed

Druma, as discussed in my question [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38525/were-there-two-vijaya-bows-belonging-to-indra-at-time-of-mahabharata) had given Vijaya bow to Rukmi. However this question is on Lord Parashurama. If not mistaken he had taken a vow to not train kshatriyas. So how come he had accepted Rukmi as a student ? What's the story behind it ?

Comment: Parshuram also taught Bhishma, a Kshatriya. No?

Comment: @sbharti - Parhuram taught Bhishma before Bhishma or Shantanu were aware Bhishma was Shantanu's son. https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01101.htm